# Getting NullPointerException while starting Activity in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use Intent to start ArrAdapter.java from FileEvent.java class. In startActivity(), I am getting null pointer exception. FileEvent.java extends an activity, but does not have setContentView(). Because I am not displaying anything on UI in this this class. Please see the following code -

FileEvent.java :-

```
    public class FileEvent extends Activity implements ObserverActivity{
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";
    public static String path2;
    public String filename;
    public String path; 
    MyFileObserver myFileObserver; 
    public adapter info ;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapterarr;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           this.info  = new adapter(this); 

        myFileObserver = new MyFileObserver("/storage/sdcard/DCIM/SAMPLE_IMAGES/");
            myFileObserver.registerObserver(this);
            myFileObserver.startWatching();
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
}

     protected void onPause(){
            myFileObserver.stopWatching();
            myFileObserver.unregisterObserver(this); 
          } 

          protected void onResume(){
            myFileObserver.registerObserver(this);
            myFileObserver.startWatching();
          }
    public void insert(String path) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      try{

    this.info = new adapter(this);
    this.filename = path; 

    if(info == null)
    {
        System.out.println("info is null here.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("info is not null here.");
    //  setpath(path);
        System.out.println("sharedpreferences "+FileEvent.path2);

        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.ArrAdapter")); //Here I am getting the NullPointerException.


       // i.putExtra("path", path);

        /*  }
        }

    private void setpath(String path) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FileEvent.path2 = path;

}
    public void delete(String path) {
        Log.v("entered delete() in FileEvent", "entered delete() in FileEvent");

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
this.info = new adapter(this);
try{
    if(this.info == null)
    {
        System.out.println("this.info is null here");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("this.info is not null here");
          int id_of_deleted_person_photo = info.deletefile(path);
Log.v("_id of FileName to delete : ", ""+id_of_deleted_person_photo+"");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("Error in delete() in FileEvent.java : ",e.toString());
        }
        Log.v("completed delete() in FileEvent", "completed delete() in FileEvent");
    }
    @Override
    public void onFileObserved(int Event, String path) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("path in onFileObserved",path);
    }
```

ArrAdapter.java :-

```
public class ArrAdapter extends ListActivity{
public String path;
ListView listView;
public adapter info;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterarr;
private String filename;
public Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fileeventlist);
info = new adapter(this);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    Log.v("value of FileEvent.path2 : ",FileEvent.path2);
        insert(FileEvent.path2);
        }
        private void insert(String var_from_prev_intent1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                int rowcount = info.getrowcountofpersons(); 
                    Log.v("rowcount in new list onCreate: ", 

""+info.getrowcountofpersons()+"");
                String[] values = new String[rowcount];
            for(int i =1;i<=rowcount;i++)
            {
                values[i-1]=info.getPersonList(i); 
                System.out.println("in for loop now"+values[i-1]);
            } 
            this.adapterarr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values); 
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.v("Error at ArrayAdapter : ",e.toString());
            }
            if(adapterarr == null)
            {
                System.out.println("2. Here adapterarr is null.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("2. Here adapterarr is not null.");
            }



            listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);

            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);


            // Assign adapter to List
            setListAdapter(adapterarr);  
            //  new Bullet(info).execute((Void)null);


        }


protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

//  try{

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
          // ListView Clicked item index
           int itemPosition     = position;
          // ListView Clicked item value
           String  itemValue    = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
         //  content.setText("Click : \n  Position :"+itemPosition+"  \n  ListItem : " +itemValue);
           String personname = itemValue;
           try
           {
               System.out.println("paths in FileEvent : "+filename);
               info.insert(filename,personname);
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

    /*  }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("Error in insert() definition FileEvent.java : ",e.toString());
        }

*/   

} }

    }
```

I am getting logcat as follows -

```
09-28 00:04:40.537: A/FileObserver(31484): Unhandled exception in FileObserver com.example.sample_fileobserver.MyFileObserver@b11cd6b8
09-28 00:04:40.537: A/FileObserver(31484): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 00:04:40.537: A/FileObserver(31484):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
09-28 00:04:40.537: A/FileObserver(31484):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
09-28 00:04:40.537: A/FileObserver(31484):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
09-28 00:04:40.537: A/FileObserver(31484):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
09-28 00:04:40.537: A/FileObserver(31484):  at com.example.sample_fileobserver.FileEvent.insert(FileEvent.java:95)
09-28 00:04:40.537: A/FileObserver(31484):  at com.example.sample_fileobserver.MyFileObserver.onEvent(MyFileObserver.java:59)
09-28 00:04:40.537: A/FileObserver(31484):  at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.onEvent(FileObserver.java:125)
09-28 00:04:40.537: A/FileObserver(31484):  at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.observe(Native Method)
09-28 00:04:40.537: A/FileObserver(31484):  at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.run(FileObserver.java:88)
```

AndroidManifest.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sample_fileobserver"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.sample_fileobserver.FileEvent"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.FIleEvent" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.sample_fileobserver.ArrAdapter"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ArrAdapter" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.sample_fileobserver.FileModificationMonitor"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 

        <service 
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:name="com.example.sample_fileobserver.FileModificationService">
    </service>
</application>
```

I have registered both the classes in the Manifest file. If not, I might have got ClassNotFound Exception. So, I am unable to understand, why this exception in raising.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried with startActivity(new Intent(FileEvent.this,ArrAdapter.class)) ?

Comment: yes, i have tried it, already @Hardy

Comment: Can you paste your AndroidManifest.xml code ?

Comment: yes @Hardy, I hace pasted in the question please see it.

Comment: ArrAdapter.java in the same package ?

Comment: yes, it is in the same package. I have a single for my entire application.

Comment: Try:startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),ArrAdapter.class))

Comment: @geet, now also I am getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure your line no. 95 is startactivity ?

Comment: Put a debug point in your ArrAdapter activity's onCreate method's 1st line and see if you reach there.

Comment: @Hardy, yes it is startActivity().

Comment: How to put debug point there @Nitin Sethi?

Comment: Use Log.d(String tag, String msg); method on your onCrerte and see in LogCat if that is printed in logs.

Comment: @NitinSethi, have placed the break point on the first line of onCreate(), there there the thread is suspended.

Comment: You can remove the FileEvent method in your class and put your ArrAdapter activity's fileeventlist xml

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38210/discussion-between-nki-and-nitin-sethi)

Answer (score 2):

Try starting your 2nd Activity using the below code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, ArrAdapter.class));
```

Comment: Did you checked [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063615/getting-nullpointerexception-while-starting-activity-in-android#comment28176493_19063615) ?

Comment: I couldn't as the net connection went off mid way and i submitted without looking into the new comments.

Comment: @Hardy and Nitin Sethi, I have tried using - startActivity(new Intent(this, ArrAdapter.class)); , startActivity(new Intent(FileEvent.this, ArrAdapter.class)); , startActivity(new Intent("com.example.sample_fileobserver.ArrAdapter")); and also startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.ArrAdapter")); All the alternatives gave the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 problems on your code. So far.

**1st startActivity**

Change your code to what @Nitin said

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, ArrAdapter.class));
```

**2nd sdcard permission**

From your code,

```
myFileObserver = new MyFileObserver("/storage/sdcard/DCIM/SAMPLE_IMAGES/");
```

I think that you are retrieving data from sdcard. To do so you need permission to external storage.
Add following code to your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Also, the SD card won't have that path in all the devices. Use Environment class to find the external directory.

Comment: After getting solved with this issue, I will change the path as you said, @NitinSethi.

Comment: @edisonthk, I have updated my code by adding permissions to the manifest file. But also getting the same error.

Comment: Are you still getting Unhandled exception in FileObserver error or only null exception

Answer (score 0):

Use Environment Class to Find SD card:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
myFileObserver = new MyFileObserver(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() +"/DCIM/SAMPLE_IMAGES/");
```

Comment: I have added the path as per your suggestion, geet. But my code is getting broken while starting the activity. Changing the file path should not affect it. Atleast, it should show the log messages in side the onCreate() of ArrAdapter class right?